# pagination not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

my controller page

```
 public function index() {
    $data['error']="";

    $data['h']="";

   $this->load->library('pagination');
     $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Imagec/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = 10;
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $data['h']=$this->Inserts_model->select($config["per_page"], $page);  
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('select_view', $data);
```

}
my mode page

```
   public function select($limit, $start)  
  {  
     $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
     $query = $this->db->get('student');  
     return $query->result();  
  }
```

my view page

```
 <p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
```

here all my code here when click on links the NOT FOUND error occur's

Comment: have you wrote any route for this url?

Comment: no, please specify..

Comment: For which url you are getting 404 error?

Comment: @kishor10d   The requested URL /ci_jib/Imagec/index/2 was not found on this server.

Comment: Do you have ```.htaccess``` in your project?

Comment: yes it is......

Comment: its strange, it must be work... can you please try it without ```.htaccess``` by providing index.php in url.

Comment: no output ...pls do share the correct code below

Comment: This link may help https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/ you do not need index in the url by default the controller goes there

Comment: You also may need to configure some routes in config/routes.php https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: @jibinkj can you upvote also for my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 100% will work

Controller :

```
public function index() {

    $data['error'] = "";

    $data['h'] = "";

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $data['h'] = $this->inserts_model->select();

    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . '/index.php/imagec/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = count($data['h']);//it will give you total no of records
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data['h'] = $this->inserts_model->select($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
//    echo "<pre>";print_r($data);die;
    $this->load->view('select_view', $data);
  }
```

Model :

```
public function select($limit=0, $start=0) {


    if (empty($start) && !empty($limit)) {
      $this->db->limit($limit);
    }
    if (!empty($start) && !empty($limit)) {
      $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('student');
    return $query->result();
  }
```