# pagination page gives 404 in codeigniter3 framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have written pagination code in Codeigniter3 framework, but when I want to go to the second, third and etc. page, it shows me 404 page. Where can be the problem? My routes file:

```
$route['courses/category/(:any)'] = 'courses/all_courses/$1';
$route['courses/(:any)'] = 'courses/single_course/$1';
```

My controller:

```
public function all_courses($categories_slug = NULL, $offset = 0) {

            //pagination
            $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'courses/category/'.$categories_slug;
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('courses');
            $config['per_page'] = 2;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 4;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);


            $data['title'] = 'Bütün Kurslar Burada';

            $data['courses'] = $this->courses_model->get_all_courses($categories_slug, $config['per_page'], $offset);


            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('courses/courses', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

My model:

```
public function get_all_courses($categories_slug = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $offset = FALSE) {
        if($limit) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }
<-- and other codes here -->
}
```

And my view:

```
<div class="col-md-12 courses_page_btn2">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li><a><?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?> </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Comment: Yesterday I answered a CodeIgniter pagination question, and I think if you read my answer it probably applies here as well. CodeIgniter pagination is really easy when you make it easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356875/codeigniter-pagination-link-is-not-working-when-i-select-the-link-in-the-view/46357044#46357044

Comment: it did not help :(

Comment: It sounds like your understanding of PHP and CodeIgniter may not be sufficient, based on your code and comment. I recommend going back and reading the entire page on Pagination in the user guide.

Comment: Have a look here https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/ You also may need to create some routes http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: check this link might be it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112609/pagination-not-working-in-codeigniter/46113419#46113419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your routes file, your route from courses/category/(:any) is set to route to courses/all_courses/$1, but your controller's all_courses method has a second parameter. So you need to do something about that. I'm guessing that since your pagination is using URI segment 4 that you'll need to adjust your route like this:

```
$route['courses/category/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'courses/all_courses/$1/$2';
```

The problem with that route is that if there is no (:num) then you'll get a 404. In most pagination schemes, you're going to want it to default to 1 (the first page). Consider this route instead:

```
$route['courses/category/(.+)'] = function ($x, $y = 1)
{
    return 'courses/all_courses/' . $x . '/' . $y;
};
```

This will route to your all_courses method, and provide both parameters, even if you leave out the second one.

This pagination works for me with that route:

```
public function all_courses( $x, $y )
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $pconfig['base_url'] = base_url() . 'courses/category/'.$x;
    $pconfig['total_rows'] = 10;
    $pconfig['per_page'] = 2;
    $pconfig['uri_segment'] = 4;

    $this->pagination->initialize($pconfig);

    echo $this->pagination->create_links();
}
```

Comment: But I did not get one thing. Should I write the second code also, or first is fine?

Comment: And there is one more problem. If this pagination shows the record on the 3rd page at the end, it shows the same element on the 4th page at the top. How can I solve it? Also, when I click 3rd page, it goes to 4th

Comment: That's really not related to your question. You asked about why you are getting a 404. Did I solve that problem? If so, you should consider accepting my answer, then start a new question for that specific need.